# Wrong Results Being Printed in C After Being Inserted in 2D Char Array

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, printf, insertion-sort

```
int const size = 100;
float grades[size];
char students[size][size];
char temp_students[size][size];

int main() {

    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;
    float g = 0;

    printf("How many students do you want to enter? \n ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    while((i < length)){

        printf("Enter the name and grade \n");
//        scanf("%s", students[i]);
        char temp;
        scanf("%c",&temp); // temp statement to clear buffer
        scanf("%[^\n]", students[i]);
        strcpy(temp_students[i], students[i]);

        printf("Enter the grade again \n");
        scanf(" %f", &g);
        grades[i] = g;

        insertion_sort_float(grades, g, length);
        insertion_sort_string(students, students[i], length);

        i++;
    }
    i--;

    print_report(grades, students, length);

}

void print_report(float grades[], char students[size][size], int number){

   printf("Students Test Report \n");

   printf("Students that took the test: %d \n", number);

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < number; j++){
            printf("%c", students[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    double average = average_number(grades, number);
    double median = median_number(grades, number);
    double highest = max_number(grades, number);
    double lowest = min_number(grades, number);

    printf("Average: %f \n Median: %f \n Highest: %f \n Lowest: %f \n", average, median, highest, lowest);


 }

void insertion_sort_string(char students[size][size], char string[], int array_size) {
    if (array_size+ 1 < size) {// only do insert when there is free space in array
        if (array_size == 0)//empty array, insert at the top directly
            strcpy(students[0], string);

        int insert_index;//to identify the location
        for (int i = 0; i < array_size + 1; i++) {
            insert_index = i;
            if (strcmp(students[i], string)) // due the sorted property of array,
                break;// where the first bigger item showes up, where we should insert    

        }//end of the first for loop
        // if we don't find any bigger item, inset_index will equal to element_num, which means we insert at the tail

        for (int j = array_size; j > insert_index; j--) {
            strcpy(students[j], students[j-1]);

        }// end of the second loop
        strcpy(students[insert_index], string); // do the insert    
    } else {
        printf("overflow!");
        return;
    }
}
```

This is what happens when the code is run:

[image: Output]

Write a program that allows a user to enter the names of students that took a test along with the grades they received.

I am not sure why none of the other names are being stored. Only Gerar is being printed. Also the entire string should be printed: "Gerard 78.5", but that is not happening either.

***Some code omitted for post purposes. But important code is included***

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf()` and I think you'll see the problem.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `scanf()`. Use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Comment: The reason it's only printing `Gerar` is because you only print the first `length` characters of each name. But `length` is the number of names, it has nothing to do with the length of the names.

Comment: what do you mean "first length characters"? And how would I fix this?

Comment: Use `printf("%s\n", students[i])` to print out the whole name, instead of printing it character by character with `length` as the limit.

Comment: It's because of this loop: `for(int j = 0; j < number; j++){`

Comment: Why do you ask them to enter the grade twice?

Comment: The way you're inserting the names and grades into separate arrays, which are each sorted, the grades won't end up in the same place as the names. It would be better to use an array of `struct` that keeps the name and grade together.

Comment: How did you compile this? The code isn't valid C. Are you actually using a C++ compiler?